# References to a comment on a deleted answer can break Stack Exchange JS

Tags: bug, user-interface, editor

For the following URL, JavaScript breaks:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356382/splitting-a-braces-grouped-string-in-python/16356421?noredirect=1#comment23433042_16356421
```

This is a link to a [deleted comment on a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356382/splitting-a-braces-grouped-string-in-python/16356421?noredirect=1#comment23433042_16356421), the answer I can see as a 10K+ user (although users <10k [see the error too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178879/references-to-a-comment-on-a-deleted-answer-can-break-stack-exchange-js#comment540369_178879)).

With Chrome (26, Mac OS X) the console sez:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

for line 83 of `full.js`.

Firefox (20, Mac still), the web console spits out:

```
[12:48:28.459] TypeError: c.attr(...) is undefined @ http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=c9131e40e3fb:83
```

Safari (6.0.4 on, you guessed it, Mac OS X) has this to complain about:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'c.attr("id").replace')
```

for line 83 of `full.js`.

Because of this, the Answer text box on Stack Overflow is lacking all niceties such as an actual WMD editor.

If you remove the hash reference `#comment23433042_16356421` from the end of the URL, things work again. Removing the `?noredirect=1` query parameter makes no difference.

Comment: Weird, I can't reproduce it on the example you linked (which is good, because it means it's probably fixed and just propagating caches).

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Firefox 20 on my Mac, not even on that page.

Comment: @TimPost: As I investigate further, it seems to be limited to just one page. Since I don't have extensions installed in Safari, I am at least confident that it is not a local-to-my-browser-setup problem.

Comment: Interesting, it's the comment link..

Comment: @TimPost: Narrowed it down to the comment hash ref.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: narrowed it down somewhat. Can you reproduce it with the comment reference?

Comment: Yes, now I can.

Comment: `self.find(...)[0]` could to be related to Greasemonkey or its (SE related) scripts. When I disable it, only `c.attr(...) is undefined` occurs. I'm unable to see deleted posts though.

Comment: @DanielBeck: Yes, with GM disabled only that line remains, so removed the other entry.

Comment: @DanielBeck: So you can reproduce it without seeing deleted posts? Interesting.